# How do I prevent the MUI Dialog to close when I do any action?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I prevent the MUI Dialog to close when I do any action inside the dialog box. If I am clicking on the backdrop it should close, yes. But when I click on any input inside the dialog box or anywhere, it closes.

I have a JSX page which has this:

```
 {travel.people.map((person, i) => {
      person.entrys.map((entry, index) => {

     return <Entry entry={entry} index={index +1} waypoints={travel.waypoints} />
    })
 })}
```

So basically every person in that array has an array of entries and I want every time a user clicks an " Entry " component to display a dialog with the Entry's info.

this is the Entry component:

```
import { Avatar, Button, Dialog, DialogContent, DialogTitle, MenuItem, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useState } from 'react'




const Entry = ({ entry, index, waypoints }) => {
    const [display, setDisplay] = useState(false);
    const [dataToParse, setDataToParse] = useState({
        start: {
            index:'',
            from:'',
            to:''
        },
        end: {
            index:'',
            from:'',
            to:''
        }
    })

   
      
    return (
        <div onClick={() => setDisplay(true)}>
            <Avatar style={{ marginLeft: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px', background: 'green', fontSize: '12px' }}>{index}</Avatar>
            <Dialog
                open={display}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
                onClose={() => setDisplay(false)}
                disableEscapeKeyDown
            >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                    Edit this entry
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column', width:'100%'}}>
                        <p>Start: <strong>{entry.start.from} to {entry.start.to} </strong></p>
                      
                            <TextField
                                select
                                label="Starting Waypoint"
                        
                                fullWidth
                            >
                                {waypoints.map((option, index) => (
                                    <MenuItem key={index +1} value={index +1} onClick={() => setDataToParse({ ...dataToParse, start: {index: index+1, from: option.from, to: option.to} })}>
                                        {option.from} to {option.to}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </TextField>
                            <p>End: <strong>{entry.end.from} to {entry.end.to} </strong></p>
                      
                            <TextField
                                select
                                label="Ending Waypoint"
                            
                                fullWidth
                            >
                                {waypoints.map((option, index) => (
                                    <MenuItem key={index +1} value={index +1} onClick={() => setDataToParse({ ...dataToParse, end: {index: index+1, from: option.from, to: option.to} })}>
                                        {option.from} to {option.to}
                                    </MenuItem>
                                ))}
                            </TextField>

                            <Button>Save</Button>
                    </div>
                </DialogContent>

            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Entry
```

Every time I trigger those TextFields or click anywhere else in the Dialog box, it closes. How Can I prevent that and actual do stuff on that dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the `div` that has the `onClick={() => setDisplay(true)}` involves all content from `Entry` component, including the `Dialog`. Try to separate the `Avatar` and `Dialog` like this:

```
const Entry = ({ entry, index, waypoints }) => {
  // Some code above the return
  // ...

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={() => setDisplay(true)}>
        <Avatar style={{ marginLeft: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px', background: 'green', fontSize: '12px' }}>{index}</Avatar>
      </div>
      <Dialog
        open={display}
        aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
        onClose={() => setDisplay(false)}
        disableEscapeKeyDown
      >
        {/* The dialog content */}
      </Dialog>
    </>
  )
}
```